# Driving a power transistor with 2sc945

Tags: voltage-regulator, feedback, power-supply

I'm designing a simple 15V to 5V DC voltage feadback mode non SMPS regulator.

I'm using E13007E2 power NPN switch mode transistor. And to drive that transistor
I'm using C945 another transistor.

This is my schematic diagram of the circuit.

[image]

It gives 4.5V output when it's not loaded. But when it's loaded and after some 
time the C945 had gone. It's 2 junctions are open now.  c945 is to shunt just only
6mA. Why it can't handle 6mA?

Any idea how could I calculate the operating points precisely?

Comment: I hope you didn't really apply 200V -- that would have done it!

Comment: sorry , that for only simulation. See the edited new picture.

Comment: I honestly can't think of any reason that the transistor would have failed as a result of that circuit design. Perhaps it was "just its time." :-) Can you provide any other details about your setup and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DaveTweed I want to build a 15v to 5v Dc2DC converter.
Fortunately I got another C945 Tr-1. it also work some long and gone.

Comment: Is there any chance you've misunderstood which pin is which on either of the transistors?

Comment: I've double and triple checked. And I let somebody else to do a peer review of wiring.Everything is in correct place.

Comment: Now I got three ex transistors left me. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circuit Lab has simulations
[image: Series Voltage Regulator]
[Link to the above circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/f42m94/series-voltage-regularor/)
They did not have your parts number in their library.